# How to convert a Record type to string in-line with Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

I have a Ballerina `record` type as below.

```
type Flight record {
    int flightNo;
    string airline;
    int price;
    !...
};
```

I want to convert this to a string in a single line. Tried below but gives compilation errors.

```
log:printDebug("Response : " + check <string> <json> flight but {error => {}});
```

In above, `Flight` to `json` error is handled using `but`. `json` to `string` error is omitted with check. But it still gives below error.

```
incompatible types: 'json|error' cannot be converted to 'string'
```

It seems Ballerina did not take `<json> flight but {error => {}}` as a whole which returns only a `json` but, `<json> flight` which returns either `json` or `error`. If this was Java, i could've simply surrounded them with parenthesis `check <string> (<json> flight but {error => {}})`. But, this doesn't seem to work either.

My question is, is it logical (fair) to fail what i already tried? Can we do this in-line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ballerina, if you want to convert a `json` to `string`, then you have to use the inbuilt `toString()` function on the json variable.

So if your requirement is to first convert the record to `json` and then to `string`, following example code would help. If you want directly convert/format a `record` to `string`, then you could use the `sprintf` function as given in the second case, which could format the given record to string.

```
import ballerina/io;
type Flight record {
    int flightNo;
    string airline;
    int price;
    !...
};

public function main(string... args) {
    Flight flight = {flightNo:1234, airline:"SL", price:54321};

    // record to json and then to string
    json j = check <json> flight;
    string jStr = j.toString();
    io:println(jStr);

    // record to string
    string rStr = io:sprintf("%s", flight);
    io:println(rStr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

Yes it it legal to inline according to the spec, no it's not implemented yet, I think we can expect it to be implemented soon.

As @Kishanthan mentioned in his answer there are two ways to convert Json to string, but current Ballerina implementation does not allow them to use in a single line.

According to Ballerina spec, `string jStr = (<json> flight but {error => <json> ""}).toString();` is legal, heck even `<json> flight but {error => <json> ""}.toString();` seems to be legal. At the moment ballerina compiler doesn't seems to allow method calls on a expression, it only support method calls on a variable reference.

You can find the current version of the specifications under [https://ballerina.io/learn/](https://ballerina.io/res/Ballerina-Language-Specification-WD-2018-07-12.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

convert Record to json:
`json|error flightJson = json.convert(flight);`

convert Record to map:
`map<anydata>|error flightMap = map<anydata>.convert(flight);`

convert json to Record:
`Flight|error flight = Flight.convert(flightJson);`

convert json to string:
`string flightString = flightJson.toString();`

Currently there's no convert from Record to string. You'll need to take it through json or map and deal with potential **error**s, or use sprintf as suggested above.

[Look this example](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/json-record-map-conversion.html)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Also, the link is broken.